# Can I Instantiate Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan)?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, instance, instantiation, microsoft-edge

Is it/Will it be possible to instantiate Microsoft Edge (formerly codenamed Project Spartan), the web browser that replaces Internet Explorer, in a WPF window? Will it be a component for WPF?

Comment: Microsoft has provided some insight in a recent blog. More details are promised at Build 2015. There will be a new renderer engine for the WebView control:  "New rendering engine: The new engine frees you from having to do platform-specific work to deliver a consistent mobile experience and is included in Internet Explorer 11, in our new ‘Project Spartan’ browser, and will be used by the WebView control."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, IE and Microsoft Edge are two different browsers, so Edge is not considered to be the "new IE", at least not by impression. Instead it's more of a "new browser" from Microsoft.

Until Microsoft Edge is officially released, we will never know how our apps can interact with it, though I heard it will be part of the next preview build after the January Preview Build.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/01/22/project-spartan-and-the-windows-10-january-preview-build.aspx

I'm assuming Microsoft Edge will be executed under a process, and similar to any process running in Windows, it can be instantiated by your code. I do hope they will release an SDK for Edge.

Once the images are available - along with the browser itself, you might want to try and install VS (not ideal and not sure if installation will allow you) so you can see how you can interact with Edge.

Comment: As of Build 10074, Microsoft Edge is available to use. I'm using it right now to view this answer. :)